# Find specific property with reflection by examining its generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Let's say I have The class

```
public partial class MyEntities: DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
     public DbSet<CustomerInfo> CustomerInfos {get;set;}
     public DbSet<Order> Orders {get;set;}
     // etc
}
```

How can I find the property that has the generic type `Customer`?

In other words I am looking to create the method:

```
 public PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(){
     var allProperties = TypeOf(MyEntities).GetProperties();
     // implementation
 }
```

If I call the method as `GetProperty<Customer>()` then I will like to get the first property. If I call the method as `GetProperty<Order>()` then I will like to get the last property. How can I examine the `<Type>` with reflection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Type.IsGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Type.GetGenericArguments()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
public PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(){
    var allProperties = TypeOf(MyEntities).GetProperties();
    return allProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType
        && prop.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault() == typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: small change though I don't see the GenericTypeArguments property so I did `prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @TonoNam oh, I guess "GenericTypeArguments" is new in .Net 4.5.  I've updated.